# Display lowest cost of an item over various databases using only part number and cost

Tags: sql, ms-access, min, union-all

I have 3 databases (actual query seperated below) that I have union queried together. I am trying to get the lowest cost among the 3 based upon one MFG PART NO.
The one common is the MFG PART NO so I would like that as a result along with the lowest price from all 3 suppliers.
I have created a union query that looks like this:

```
SELECT INGRAM.[MFG NAME], INGRAM.[MFG PART NO], INGRAM.[DESCRIPT 1] AS DESCRIPTION, INGRAM.Cost, INGRAM.MLP AS [LIST PRICE], INGRAM.[INGRAM PARTNO] AS [VENDOR SKU], INGRAM.LGTH AS COO
FROM INGRAM

UNION ALL 

SELECT [SYNNEX CURRENT].[MFG NAME], [SYNNEX CURRENT].[MFG PART NO], [SYNNEX CURRENT].[Part Description] AS DESCRIPTION, [SYNNEX CURRENT].Cost, [SYNNEX CURRENT].MSRP AS [LIST PRICE], [SYNNEX CURRENT].[SYNNEX SKU] AS [VENDOR SKU], [SYNNEX CURRENT].[Country of Origin] AS COO
FROM [SYNNEX CURRENT]

UNION ALL 

SELECT [Digitek Product Catalog].Manufacturer AS [MFG NAME], [Digitek Product Catalog].[Part No] AS [MFG PART NO], [Digitek Product Catalog].Description AS DESCRIPTION, [Digitek Product Catalog].[Unit Price] AS Cost, [Digitek Product Catalog].[List Price], [Digitek Product Catalog].[Part No] AS [VENDOR SKU], [Digitek Product Catalog].[Country Of Origin] AS COO
FROM [Digitek Product Catalog]
ORDER BY [MFG PART NO];
```

This combines all the catalogs into one.

I then run another query to try and get the min from the cost column, BUT since the MFG NAME column contains different names for the same manufacturer (depending on the supplier) as well the VENDOR SKU is different for them as well.

I want a result that displays all of my information but returns only the best costs among the same MFG PART NO common items.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with a top 1 query.

```
Select TOP 1 * FROM <yourunionquery> ORDER BY Cost
```

If there is more than one with the same price you will get multiple rows. In that case, simply add another field to the sort. E.G. ORDER BY Cost, [MFG Name]